# How to add dashes (separate the response)

Tags: python

The final result is bunched together, it needs to be separate.

Here is my code:

```
a = input('Clubhouse location: ')

for char in a:
  code = str(ord(char))
  b = a.replace(a, code)
  print(b, end='')
```

Here is my result:

```
Clubhouse location: Treehouse
84114101101104111117115101
```

Here is what it is supposed to be:

```
Clubhouse location: Treehouse
84-114-101-101-104-111-117-115-101
```

Comment: `print("-".join(str(ord(char)) for char in a))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
a = input('Clubhouse location: ')

print("-".join(str(ord(char)) for char in a))
# --> 84-114-101-101-104-111-117-115-101
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
a = input('Clubhouse location: ')
print('-'.join(str(ord(ch)) for ch in a))
```

Also you can [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) charcodes into `print()` and use [`sep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) argument:

```
print(*(ord(ch) for ch in a), sep='-')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `-` (if `char` isn't the last in string `a`) as an end argument to the `print` function:

```
a = input('Clubhouse location: ')

for i, char in enumerate(a):
  code = str(ord(char))
  b = a.replace(a, code)
  end = '-' if i < len(a) - 1 else ''
  print(b, end = end)
```

Comment: i will print unexpected `-` in the end, isn't it?

Comment: @Travis Fixed it with a test for last `char`.